# How to set a different output directory for different configurations on vstudio19?

Tags: visual-studio

I have set one output directory to the `configuration: release`
and when I try to set another directory to the `configuration: self-contained`
it also does changes the directory of `release`.

**like this :**

[image: gif]

Is not possible for each configuration to have one output directory?

Currently using `visual studio 2019` and the project language is `c++`.

Comment: Each configuration can have a different output directory. I have Bin\Debug and Bin\Release in many of my projects with Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: When you change some properties for one configuration and then select a different configuration (from the drop-down), a dialog box appears, asking whether you want to save the changes made to the previously selected configuration or not. The GIF is cropped, so we don't see how you answer that question.

Comment: @heapunderrun i clicked apply before changing, i added a new gif.